Помогите пожалуйста с установкой sfml через cmake FetchContent
Пользуюсь macOS, мучаюсь с установкой sfml. Всё вроде установила, но ошибка в cmakelist. Помогите пожалуйста, что нужно исправить?
Вот что пишу в CMakeList:
project(NewSFMLProject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(INC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
        GIT_TAG 2.6.1 sfml)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INC_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE sfml-graphics)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME})

Код программы:




#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480,32),"Hello SFML");
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
    sf::Text text("Hello World",font,11);
    text.setCharacterSize(32);
    text.setPosition(window.getSize().x/2 - text.getGlobalBounds().width/2,
                     window.getSize().y/2 - text.getGlobalBounds().height/2);

    while(window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(text);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


**Ошибка:**



[2/9] Performing update step for 'sfml-populate'
CMake Error at /Users/al/Documents/CLionProjects/NewSFMLProject/cmake-build-debug/_deps/sfml-subbuild/sfml-populate-prefix/tmp/sfml-populate-gitupdate.cmake:34 (message):
  Failed to get the hash for HEAD:

  fatal: not a git repository: '.git'



FAILED: sfml-populate-prefix/src/sfml-populate-stamp/sfml-populate-update /Users/al/Documents/CLionProjects/NewSFMLProject/cmake-build-debug/_deps/sfml-subbuild/sfml-populate-prefix/src/sfml-populate-stamp/sfml-populate-update 
cd /Users/al/Documents/CLionProjects/NewSFMLProject/cmake-build-debug/_deps/sfml-src && /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/bin/cmake -Dcan_fetch=YES -P /Users/al/Documents/CLionProjects/NewSFMLProject/cmake-build-debug/_deps/sfml-subbuild/sfml-populate-prefix/tmp/sfml-populate-gitupdate.cmake
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1679 (message):
  Build step for sfml failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1819:EVAL:2 (__FetchContent_directPopulate)
  /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1819 (cmake_language)
  /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:2033 (FetchContent_Populate)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (FetchContent_MakeAvailable)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[Failed to reload]```


У вас ошибка в FetchContent_Declare в последней строке
        GIT_TAG 2.6.1 sfml)
                      ^^^^

вот это не нужно.
Должно быть:
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
        GIT_TAG 2.6.1)

Еще у меня cmake ругался на отсутствие cmake_minimum_required первой строкой в CMakeLists.

не помогло, всё та же ошибка

перепроверил, у меня все работает. попробуйте удалить папку с билдом чтобы cmake заново стянул код, а не пытался переиспользовать скаченный
